# I have some time series data dumped on my Hbase. Can I take this data and report using OpenTSDB?

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I have some time series data dumped on my Hbase. Can I take this data and report using OpenTSDB? If so is there is a video tutorials or documents where i can start up with this.

Comment: Aren't there tutorials on hbase and opentsdb (separately)?

Comment: What do you mean by "report" ? OpenTSDB documentation says you should NOT write directly into HBase but use their API. So the solution would be to export it from Hbase and import it into OpenTSDB, but they'll be data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OpenTSDB ends up writing data to HBASE in certain format. It maintains its own HBase tables. Take a look at http://sunilsbjoshi.blogspot.in/2015/09/understanding-opentsdb-tables.html

As long as your existing data is not as mentioned, then you just cant use OpenTSDB on top of it.